# Convert Java nested class to JSON using JAX-RS

Tags: java, android, json, jersey, jax-rs

I basically want to send an object of class `Customer` as JSON to android from my JAVA REST API.

My `Customer` class looks like this:

```
public class Customer {
    private long customerId;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String gender;
    private long accountId;

    class Account {
        private long accountId;
        private int balance;
    }
}
```

The JSON I am expecting should look like this:

```
{
 "customerId": "something",
 "firstName": "something",
 "middleName": "something",
 "gender": "M or F",
 "accountId": "something",
 "Account": {
  "accountId": "something",
  "balance": "something",
 } 
}
```

**Extra Information:**

I use this dependency for conversion to JSON.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

How can I make an object of this class so that it's JSON conversion by JAX-RS look like this?

Answer (score 0):

Outer class could have more than one inner class instance. If you want to marshall it to JSON, you should tell, what instance to use. For this, I suppose to add `Account account` field into outer class. Then, you need to add getters/setters for private fields and `XmlElement` annotations. Finally, it will look like this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Customer {
    private long customerId;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String gender;
    private long accountId;
    private Account account;

    class Account {
        private long accountId;
        private int balance;

        @XmlElement(name = "accountId")
        public long getAccountId() {
            return accountId;
        }
        public void setAccountId(long accountId) {
            this.accountId = accountId;
        }
        @XmlElement(name = "balance")
        public int getBalance() {
            return balance;
        }
        public void setBalance(int balance) {
            this.balance = balance;
        }
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "customerId")
    public long getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
    public void setCustomerId(long customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "firstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "middleName")
    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }
    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "lastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "gender")
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "accountId")
    public long getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }
    public void setAccountId(long accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "account")
    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }
    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
}
```

Now, you could use instances of this class with Jersey client like this:

```
Entity e = Entity.entity(customer, "application/json");
Response r = invocationBuilder.method("POST", e);
```